# Facebook android app discards #hashtag passed via Intent. But it works on iOS

Tags: android, ios, facebook, hashtag

I know there are already few threads that talk about Facebook (FB) android app only taking the URL (and discarding rest) from text that is added to the passed Intent with key Intent.EXTRA_TEXT. But turns out #hashtag works with FB iOS app.

Say, I pass

> This is a share text. #hashtag www.link.com

to FB iOS app. FB iOS app correctly renders the #hashtag and a card for [www.link.com](http://www.liink.com). However, if the same text is passed to FB android app, it only renders a card for [www.link.com](http://www.link.com). I don't know the exact code used in iOS but the mechanism seems quite similar to that of Android. Here is how I am doing it on Android,

```
Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
facebookIntent.setType("text/plain");
facebookIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "www.link.com");
facebookIntent.setPackage(FACEBOOK_PACKAGE_NAME);
startActivityForResult(facebookIntent, REQUEST_FACEBOOK_NATIVE_SHARE);
```

I tried reporting this at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create/?legacy_version=true but couldn't find appropriate answer for the first question they ask,

> Please select the type of bug you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. I encouter the same problem : hashtag works with iOS and doesn't with Android. Did you have success to get it work on Android since?

Comment: @Don, nope. No success to get it work on Android.